# How can I use if statement in let statement?

Tags: sml

I would like this to work:

```
fun function (i) =
   let 
       if i = 1 then
           val h = valOf(Int.fromString(valOf(TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)))
       else
           val h = someFunction();
   in

       code...
   end
```

But it seems like you can't declare a value like that... How should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `if` statement in ML is an expression. That means it has to have a value. Remember, value declaration in SML looks like this:

```
val <name> = <expression>
```

Since an `if ... then ... else` statement is an expression, you can put in on the right side of the `=`.

```
fun function i =
  let
    val h = if i = 1 then ...
                     else ...
  in
    ...
  end
```

Another thing. Remember that `valOf` can go wrong. Using it on input is pretty much asking for your program to crash, since the user could type in anything.

Comment: What would you use instead of valOf then? Can I handle the exeption option raised in some way? Like in a if.. else statement?

Comment: I'd probably use pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
fun function(i)=
   let 
        fun nextInput() =
            case (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn) of
                NONE => 0
              | SOME s => case Int.fromString(s) of
                            NONE => 0
                          | SOME n => n

        val h = if i = 1 then nextInput() else someFunction()
   in
        code...
   end
```

This way you cover the cases in which the user may not enter a number, but anything else, or nothing at all.